# R suppressing rownames in grid table

Tags: r, gridextra

I can produce a table with gridExtra:

eg:

```
    library(gridExtra)
    grid.table(head(iris))
```

But this produces a rownames column 1:6.
Is there a way to be able to suppress the rownames column so that it does not appear in the table?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just add `rows = NULL`:

```
grid.table(head(iris), rows = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: The parameter `show.rownames` seems to be no longer available.

Comment: @banan3'14, good catch, now is not longer a parameter of this function.

Comment: @Jilber I edited the answer removing the unavailable option.