# Is it possible to view an HTML table in the viewer pane?

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to know if there is any function which makes it easy to visualize an html object in the RStudio's viewer pane. For instance, I would like to know if it would be possible to view an html table in the viewer pane.

```
library("Quandl")
library("knitr")
df  <-  Quandl("FBI_UCR/USCRIME_TYPE_VIOLENTCRIMERATE")
kable(head(df[,1:9]), format = 'html', table.attr = "class=nofluid")
```

Comment: I think you can convert your object to a gridTable grob in `gridExtra` package and plot that (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045396/r-suppressing-rownames-in-grid-table).

Comment: Nice trick but that's not an HTML table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a quick way to do this in RStudio

```
view_kable <- function(x, ...){
  tab <- paste(capture.output(kable(x, ...)), collapse = '\n')
  tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
  writeLines(tab, tf)
  rstudio::viewer(tf)
}
view_kable(head(df[,1:9]), format = 'html', table.attr = "class=nofluid")
```

If the `kable` function can return an object of class `kable`, then one could rename `view_kable` as `print.kable` in which case merely calling the `kable` function would open the table in the viewer. If you think this is useful, please go ahead and file a feature request on the `knitr` github page.

Comment: Works nicely, although requires changing rstudio::viewer to rstudioapi::viewer

Answer (score 23):

I have a solution that works for kable tables.

```
kable(iris) %>% kableExtra::kable_styling()
```

This is automatically displayed in the viewer pane. No need for tempfile.

Answer (score 13):

I have this functionality in my [htmlTable](https://cran.r-project.org/package=htmlTable) package and the function is rather simple:

```
print.htmlTable<- function(x, useViewer = TRUE, ...){
  # Don't use viewer if in knitr
  if (useViewer &&
        !"package:knitr" %in% search()){

    htmlFile <- tempfile(fileext=".html")
    htmlPage <- paste("<html>",
                      "<head>",
                      "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=UTF-8\">",
                      "</head>",
                      "<body>",
                      "<div style=\"margin: 0 auto; display: table; margin-top: 1em;\">",
                      x,
                      "</div>",
                      "</body>",
                      "</html>", sep="\n")
    cat(htmlPage, file=htmlFile)

    viewer <- getOption("viewer")
    if (!is.null(viewer) &&
          is.function(viewer)){
      # (code to write some content to the file)
      viewer(htmlFile)
    }else{
      utils::browseURL(htmlFile)
    }
  }else{
    cat(x)
  }
}
```

RStudio [recommends](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/viewer_pane) that you use the getOption("viewer") instead of @Ramnath's suggestion, the raw RStudio::viewer(). My solution also adds the utils::browserURL() in case you are not using RStudio. I got the idea from [this](http://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/no-need-for-spss-beautiful-output-in-r-rstats/) blog post.

Comment: Looks like [htmlTable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/index.html) is its own package now.

Comment: This is great. For those wanting view an already written file, you can easily modify the above: so (1) add a flag in the function declaration-->  print.htmlTable<- function(x, useViewer = TRUE, as.file.path = FALSE, ...);  (2) Add a small line that reads in the html if the flag is true --->  if(as.file.path){ x <- read_file(x)}; (3) create the following convenience wrapper function ---> view.htmlFile <- function(x, ...){ print.htmlTable(x, useViewer = TRUE, as.file.path = TRUE, ...)}; (4) Now, you can just pass the filepath to view.htmlFile and should display in the Rstudio Viewer

Answer (score 2):

As was explained on [this RStudio Support page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane), the key is to use `tempfile()` :

> Note that the Viewer pane can only be used for local web content. This
>   content can either be static HTML files written to the session
>   temporary directory (i.e. files with paths generated by the tempfile
>   function) or a locally run web application.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954623/view-markdown-generated-html-in-rstudio-viewer/27119882#27119882) for a bare-bones example.

Answer (score 1):

For `kable` objects, we can use `print.kableExtra`

```
library(knitr)

x <- kable(head(iris), format = "html")

library(kableExtra)

class(x) <- c("kableExtra", class(x))
print(x)
```