# View markdown generated html in RStudio viewer

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to see `html` file that is generated using `markdown` in **RStudio viewer**, but `rstudio::viewer('test.html')` opens my file in browser outside RStudio. Could you tell me how can I achieve this?

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863771/is-it-possible-to-view-an-html-table-in-the-viewer-pane) example works but I don't know why my example doesn't work in that way.

`test.html` file it'a an complied example that we get when we choose new file -> R Markdown.

**EDIT** (according to Roman Luštrik comment)

```
library(knitr)
library(markdown)
f <- system.file("examples", "knitr-minimal.Rmd", package = "knitr")
knit(f)
markdownToHTML('knitr-minimal.md',output='knitr-minimal.html')
rstudio::viewer('knitr-minimal.html')
```

Comment: Can you post a small, reproducible example that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Ok, here is example taken from `knitr` and html generated using `markdown` package

Answer (score 8):

The key is using `tempfile()`, as explained [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane). Whenever the html file is outside the session temp dir, Rstudio won't display it.

This, on the other hand, will work:

```
temp.f <- tempfile()
cat("Hello", file = temp.f)
rstudio::viewer(temp.f)
```

**Edit**

As was pointed out by @Sebastian Palma in his comment, the "rstudio" package has been replaced by "rstudioapi", so that the third line should now be:

```
rstudioapi::viewer(temp.f)
```

Comment: It might differ from current versions. Use `rstudioapi::viewer(...)` instead.

Answer (score 6):

On my version of RStudio (0.98.994), clicking on the small down arrow on the right side of the "knit HTML"button gives me the options "View in Pane" and "View in Window". Selecting the first instead of the second fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

A nice comprehensive solution can be found by modifying the response given here:
[Is it possible to view an HTML table in the viewer pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863771/is-it-possible-to-view-an-html-table-in-the-viewer-pane) Or, for convenience, I have copied the full code at the end

Specifically, modify the definition of print.htmlTable with the following three simple steps:

**(1) Add a flag to the function declaration as follows:**

```
print.htmlTable<- function(x, useViewer = TRUE, as.file.path = FALSE, ...)
```

**(2) In the function definition, add the following line:**

```
if(as.file.path){ x <- read_file(x)}
```

**(3) Create a wrapper function to view file:**

```
view.htmlFile <- function(x, ...){
     print.htmlTable(x, useViewer = TRUE, as.file.path = TRUE, ...) 
     }
```

**(4) Now, you can use the wrapper to view HTML files using the file path**
*(and, the original function to view unsaved html outputs):*

```
 view.htmlFile(filepath.to.html) #i.e. 'knitr-minimal.html' or any other html file
```

*Reminder: this is tweak / modification of the original function written by [Max Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409508/max-gordon) in an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863771/is-it-possible-to-view-an-html-table-in-the-viewer-pane). Credit given accordingly.*

```
print.htmlTable<- function(x, useViewer = TRUE, as.file.path = FALSE, ...){

  if(as.file.path){ x <- read_file(x)}

  # Don't use viewer if knitr package is loaded (assumes if you loaded knitr, you are using knitr and dont want to use Viewer)
if (useViewer && !"package:knitr" %in% search()){

    htmlFile <- tempfile(fileext=".html")
    htmlPage <- paste("<html>", 
                      "<head>",
                      "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=UTF-8\">", 
                      "</head>",
                      "<body>", 
                      "<div style=\"margin: 0 auto; display: table; margin-top: 1em;\">",
                      x,
                      "</div>",
                      "</body>",
                      "</html>", sep="\n")
    cat(htmlPage, file=htmlFile)

    viewer <- getOption("viewer")
    if (!is.null(viewer) && is.function(viewer)){
          # (code to write some content to the file)
          viewer(htmlFile)
        }else{
          utils::browseURL(htmlFile)
        }
      }else{
        cat(x)
      }
    }

#Wrapper to allow viewing of files using path
view.htmlFile <- function(x, ...){
    print.htmlTable(x, useViewer = TRUE, as.file.path = TRUE, ...) 
}

view.htmlFile(filepath.to.html)
```