# No HTML Preview in RStudio after customizing RMarkdown Renderer in .Rprofile

Tags: html, r, markdown, rstudio, r-markdown

I created the following RMarkdown Render for Rstudio, and put it in my .Rprofile.  Basically, the code moves the html file to a different location than the RMD file.   Everything works perfectly except that Rstudio no longer shows the html page in the preview viewer.  I added the line rstudio:viewer(path)  to try and force rstudio to recognize the new file path, but that doesn't work.  Any help would truly be appreciated.

```
options(rstudio.markdownToHTML = function(inputFile, outputFile) {      
    require(markdown)
    htmlOptions <- markdownHTMLOptions(defaults=TRUE)
    htmlOptions <- c(htmlOptions, "toc")

    fName = basename(outputFile)
    newOutputFile="differentPath"
    newOutputFile = paste(newOutputFile,fName, sep = "")

    markdownToHTML(inputFile, newOutputFile, options = htmlOptions)
    rstudio::viewer(newOutputFile) #trying to force RStudio to show page
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View markdown generated html in RStudio viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954623/view-markdown-generated-html-in-rstudio-viewer)