# Rmarkdown in loop, "knit html" button different output than rmarkdown::render

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

**edit**

This issue is not (necessarily) only related to {htmlTable}. The same happens when rendering a html table which has been styled with the {kableExtra} package [(see also this thread)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052689/kableextra-styled-html-tables-not-printing-when-using-rmarkdownrender-but-whe?noredirect=1&lq=1).

**original question**

I'm working in RMarkdown, trying to render a document with `htmltables` from the **htmlTable** package in a loop. When I push the "Knit" button in RStudio, everything works great. But when I use the `render()` function, the `htmltables` in the loop don't get printed, but the table just before the loop does.
I read that "knit" button and the render function does the same, so I don't understand whats wrong?

This is a working example of a `.Rmd` file with a `hmtlTables`:

````
---
output: html_document
---

## htmlTables


```{r, results='asis'}
library(data.table)
library(htmlTable)
library(ggplot2)
a <- data.table(matrix(seq(1, 100, 5), ncol = 2))
htmlTable(a)
for (i in 10:11) {
    cat( paste('## title no.', i, '\n' ) ) 
    print(ggplot(a*i, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) + geom_point())
    print(htmlTable(a*i))
    cat('\n')
}
```
````

I need to generate many reports automatically with different parameters, so I need to get this working with `render()`.

Comment: It would appear knitting is done differently.

Comment: The issue is not only with htmlTable - it also happens with kableExtra styled html tables (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052689/kableextra-styled-html-tables-not-printing-when-using-rmarkdownrender-but-whe?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

htmlTable has defined a `print` method, which appears to print the table in a new window, change `print()` to `writeLines()` will do the trick:

````
---
output: html_document
---

## htmlTables


```{r, results='asis'}
library(data.table)
library(htmlTable)
library(ggplot2)
a <- data.table(matrix(seq(1, 100, 5), ncol = 2))
htmlTable(a)
for (i in 10:11) {
    cat( paste('## title no.', i, '\n' ) ) 
    print(ggplot(a*i, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) + geom_point())
    writeLines(htmlTable(a*i))
    cat('\n')
}
```
````

---

However it still seems a bit strange to me because I believe that the knit button uses rmarkdown::render() under the hood but they have different behaviors in this case.

Comment: you saved my day with that. I'm very surprised by this behaviour and maybe someone clever knows the reason and will earn the bounty :)

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how the viewer is detected.
To check this :

````
---
title: "Check viewer"
output: html_document
---

```{r viewer, echo=FALSE}
getOption("viewer")
```
````

With `knit` button:

```
Check viewer
## NULL
```

With `rmarkdown::render`:

```
Check viewer

## function (url, height = NULL) 
## {
##     if (!is.character(url) || (length(url) != 1)) 
##         stop("url must be a single element character vector.", 
##             call. = FALSE)
##     if (identical(height, "maximize")) 
##         height <- -1
##     if (!is.null(height) && (!is.numeric(height) || (length(height) != 
##         1))) 
##         stop("height must be a single element numeric vector or 'maximize'.", 
##             call. = FALSE)
##     invisible(.Call("rs_viewer", url, height, PACKAGE = "(embedding)"))
## }
## <environment: 0x0000020ccb7f26d8>
```

`knit` button executes rendering in an environment without defined viewer, whereas `rmardown::render` in RStudio console uses interactive viewer.

`htmlTable` allows to set `options(htmlTable.cat = TRUE)`, so that `print` works, ie doesn't use interactive viewer, see `?htmlTable::htmlTable`.

> The print-function relies on the [base::interactive()] function
> for determining if the output should be sent to a browser or to the terminal.
> In vignettes and other directly knitted documents you may need to either set
> `useViewer = FALSE` alternatively set `options(htmlTable.cat = TRUE)`.

````
---
output: html_document
---

## htmlTables


```{r, results='asis'}
options(htmlTable.cat = TRUE)
library(data.table)
library(htmlTable)
library(ggplot2)
a <- data.table(matrix(seq(1, 100, 5), ncol = 2))
htmlTable(a)
for (i in 10:11) {
    cat( paste('## title no.', i, '\n' ) ) 
    print(ggplot(a*i, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) + geom_point())
    print(htmlTable(a*i))
    cat('\n')
}
```
````

Comment: @tjebo, a solution with `print`

Comment: thanks Waldi. I'll check this. However, as far as I can see, for example kableExtra is not using htmlTable and the issue is the same here. And changing the options still doesn't really explain why the knit button and the direct function call result in different outputs...

Comment: @tjebo, related post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22871109/13513328 - the above mentioned option turns `cat` on instead of triggering the viewer.

Comment: @tjebo, see update on why?