# Automatic line break in DT cell

Tags: r, dt

I'm displaying a list in a cell of a `DT` table :

```
mylist <- paste0("name",1:20)
data <- data.frame(id = 1, members = I(list(mylist))) 
DT::datatable(data)
```

The list appears on a single very long line:
[image]

I would like to have an automatic line break so that the list is split in many lines **inside the cell**, preferably according to the width of the cell.
[EDIT] this is the expected result, see [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62614668/13513328) :
[image]

I tried without success to set `DT` `ColumnDefs` options :

```
DT::datatable(data,options = list(
      autoWidth= T,
      columnDefs = list(list(width = "200" ))
  ))
```

Looks tricky as there seem to be an [issue on width option](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you asking for multiple columns?  Wrt your example 20 columns plus the Id column?

Comment: no, I want a line break in the same column, inside the cell, se my edit

Comment: I am not sure if you can achieve this via `DT` but I think, the `kableExtra` package have a feature to do what you are seeking for. Here is the [link](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html) . Have a look at the  **Grouped Columns / Rows** section please.

Comment: Thanks @maydin, this goes in the right direction. This works but is not fully practical in an interactive session due to lack of [buit-in preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863771/is-it-possible-to-view-an-html-table-in-the-viewer-pane)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a list you can use the string `"name1, name2, ..."`.

```
mylist <- paste0("name",1:20)
data <- data.frame(id = 1, members = toString(mylist)) 
datatable(data, options = list(
  columnDefs = list(
    list(width = 200, targets = 2)
  )
))
```