# How to view html in R-Studio?

Tags: html, r, html-table, datatable

In R-Studio, I am running the code from this website: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ztable/vignettes/heatmapTable.html, specifically the code below.

```
 install.packages("ztable")
 if(!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
 devtools::install_github("cardiomoon/ztable")
 require(moonBook)
 x=table(acs$Dx,acs$smoking)
 library(ztable)
 library(magrittr)
 options(ztable.type="html")
 z=ztable(x) 
 print(z,caption="Table 1. Basic Table")
```

I expected to see the table in the R-Studio Plot or Viewer pane, but instead the html text is printed in my Console pane. How can I view the table in R-Studio?

Comment: An option is to do this in `RMD` file and use ````{r ztable, results = 'asis'}
require(moonBook)
x=table(acs$Dx,acs$smoking)
library(ztable)
library(magrittr)
options(ztable.type="html")
z=ztable(x) 

print(z,caption="Table 1. Basic Table")


````

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your answer. What is an RMD file? Could you please clarify? Thank you.

Comment: In your Rstudio, you can create a new file.  There are options to create what type of file.  I updated with a solution that shows how to do that.

Comment: Do you find the option `R Markdown` when you click on Newfile option.  I updated with a screenshot of Rstudio

Comment: Great! That worked. Excellent solution. Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  I updated with another function to view that in viewer without an RMD file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create an `RMD` file (Create a new file from `Rstudio` with the option `File` -> `New File` -> `R Markdown...`)

[image]

and then specify the `results = 'asis'` in the chunk.  Click on `Knit` -> `Knit to HTML`

-RMD file content

````
---
title: "Ztable"
author: "akrun"
date: "01/11/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown



```{r ztable, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(moonBook))
x=table(acs$Dx,acs$smoking)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ztable))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(magrittr))
options(ztable.type="html")
z=ztable(x) 

print(z,caption="Table 1. Basic Table")


```
````

-output

[image]

---

Or another option if we don't want to create an `RMD` file is to create a function similar to the one showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863771/is-it-possible-to-view-an-html-table-in-the-viewer-pane)

```
view_ztable <- function(x, ...){
  tab <- paste(capture.output(ztable(x, ...)), collapse = '\n')
  tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
  writeLines(tab, tf)
  rstudioapi::viewer(tf)
}
view_ztable(x, format = 'html', table.attr = "class=nofluid")
```

-output in viewer

[image]

Comment: `print(z, type = "viewer", caption = "Table 1. Basic Table")` will output to the viewer.

Comment: Two more excellent options. Thank you both! :) - Syl