# How to display any tagList in Rstudio's viewer

Tags: r, shiny

When developing the UI of a Shiny app, I often don't want to keep running or refreshing the app to test out the effects of changes in my code, for example a tagList of text and buttons. Occasionally, like with htmlWidgets, the results of running sections of code will display in the internal viewer, but most will only display in the console.

Comment: You can use `htmltools::browsable`.

Answer (score 0):

Just generalising the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22864759/1976935:

```
in_viewer <- function(x){
  tab <- paste(capture.output(x), collapse = '\n')
  tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
  writeLines(tab, tf)
  rstudioapi::viewer(tf)
}
in_viewer(tagList(p("asdf"),actionButton("qwer","Button")))
```