# Is it possible to view an latex table in the viewer pane?

Tags: r, latex, kableextra

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863771/is-it-possible-to-view-an-html-table-in-the-viewer-pane) , I'd like to show a Latex table I make in R using the viewer. At the moment I compile it outside R to see the results but this process is very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you want but:

a) if you want to see your table **on the viewer pane:**

```
library(kableExtra)

kable(head(mtcars), booktabs = T) %>%
     kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down"))
```

b) if you want to **look at the LaTeX code** of your table in the **console**:

```
kable(mtcars, "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
     kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down"))
```

c) if you want to **save your table**:

```
kable(mtcars, "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
     kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down")) %>%
     as_image()
```

If you haven't this libraries - don't forget to **install**:

```
install.packages("magick")
install.packages("webshot")
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```